# Javascript .reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am doing freeCodeCamp JavaScript.  I am on the question:  Basic Algorithm Scripting: Factorialize a NumberPassed

Here is the code I have written:

```
function factorialize(num) {
  let arr = [];
  let reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator * currentValue;
  for (let i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
    let newArr = arr.push(i);
  }
  return newArr.reduce(reducer);
}
factorialize(5);
```

Here is my problem:  the console says this:

> ReferenceError: newArr is not defined

Why is it saying that `newArr` is not defined?  I DID define it!  I am relatively new to coding and I really want to learn. Please help me.

Comment: `push(...)` doesn't return a new array, it returns the new length of the array. You should just be doing `return arr.reduce(reducer)`. Side note, `let` makes variables block scoped so even if `push()` returned what you thought `newArr` would have only been accessible within the for loop's code block

Comment: `let newArr` creates the variable, but it only exists inside the for loop, and it's a) constantly overwritten and b) stores the new length of `arr`, since that is what `.push()` returns.

Comment: Also, you can use this: `let arr = new Array(num).fill(0).map((element, index) => index + 1);` to generate the array of `num` natural numbers.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need `newArr` at all.
2. `Array.prototype.push` returns length of the array.
3. You cannot get a variable declared with `let` in for statement and that caused an error.

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  let arr = [];
  let reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator * currentValue;
  for (let i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  return arr.reduce(reducer);
}
console.log(factorialize(5));
```

Comment: Change *"You cannot get a variable"* to *"You cannot get a `let`"*.

Answer (score 0):

you can *simply* do that

```js
const factorialize=num=>Array(num).fill(1).reduce((a,_,i)=>a*++i)

console.log('5! ->', factorialize(5) )
console.log('3! ->', factorialize(3) )
```

Comment: If you're going for short and to the point, why not make `new Array(num)`, `[num]`?

Comment: @StackSlave It is not the same thing, the first indicates the **array size** and the second only makes an array with a single element

Comment: Oh yeah... spacing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion instead of reduce if you want to:

```
function factorialize(num) {
   while (num  > 1) {
     return num * factorialize(num - 1);
        }
    return num;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was my first question on stackOverflow.  you were all very helpful!